# SQL sum or subtracted based on a column (transaction type)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to get the total quantity delivered for a given security in a SQL table. I want to calculate each line and sum them them up if they are a positive transaction type (+) [txn type] or delete that total from the rest of the results if the transaction type is negative (-). I can currently return the sum for all rows with the following code

```
SELECT     [STOCK REC NO], 
SUM(ISNULL([QTY DELIVERED], 0) + ISNULL([QTY DUE IN], 0) - ISNULL([QTY DUE OUT], 0)) AS [TOTAL QUANTITY]
FROM         bla_bla
WHERE     ([EVENT DATE] < '09/26/2012')
GROUP BY [STOCK REC NO]

TXN TYPE    QTY DELIVERED   QTY DUE IN  QTY DUE OUT EVENT DATE
+             1                                      28/11/2005
+             2                                      07/02/2006
-             3                                      22/11/2006
+             20                                     18/04/2011
+             40                                     19/04/2011
```

Comment: I don't quite follow your question.  I see the sample data.  Can you also show us sample outcome from the SELECT statement being shown?  They seem to be unrelated.  Your bottom data set, for example, doesn't have a `STOCK REC NO` column so I assume it's coming from a different table?  Are you looking to get one FINAL result or are you still trying to get it as grouped by `STOCK REC NO`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly do it this way

```
SELECT     [STOCK REC NO], 
SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN [TXN TYPE] = '-' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * [QTY DELIVERED], 0) +
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN [TXN TYPE] = '-' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * [QTY DUE IN], 0) - 
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN [TXN TYPE] = '-' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * [QTY DUE OUT], 0)) 
 AS [TOTAL QUANTITY]
FROM         bla_bla
WHERE     ([EVENT DATE] < '09/26/2012')
GROUP BY [STOCK REC NO]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [STOCK REC NO],
        CASE TXN_TYPE
            WHEN '+' THEN SUM(ISNULL([QTY DELIVERED], 0) + ISNULL([QTY DUE IN], 0) + ISNULL([QTY DUE OUT], 0))
            ELSE SUM(ISNULL([QTY DELIVERED], 0) + ISNULL([QTY DUE IN], 0) - ISNULL([QTY DUE OUT], 0))
        END AS [TOTAL QUANTITY]
FROM    bla_bla
WHERE   ([EVENT DATE] < '09/26/2012')
GROUP BY
        [STOCK REC NO]
```

Comment: This is a great answer and I thought it had something to do with the case function. This doesn't work though fully. I have to put the TXN_Type in the group by statement and only gives me the negatives and plus values. I need to subtract from the standing total..

Answer (score 0):

If `TXN_TYPE` is *always* either `+` or `-`, you could try this little trick:

```
SELECT     [STOCK REC NO], 
           SUM(
             (TXN_TYPE + '1') * (
             ISNULL([QTY DELIVERED], 0) + ISNULL([QTY DUE IN], 0) - ISNULL([QTY DUE OUT], 0)
             )
           ) AS [TOTAL QUANTITY]
FROM         bla_bla
WHERE     ([EVENT DATE] < '09/26/2012')
GROUP BY [STOCK REC NO]
```

`TXN_TYPE + '1'` becomes either `'+1'` or `'-1'`. Although it is a string, it gets implicitly converted to a number because of the multiplication.